# Custom Font Implemented with TypeFace method not changing

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

I've Read a lot of articles and stack Questions for over 4 hours, when i use this method to define a custom font i don't get any error but the font doesn't change?

My **mainactivity.java** is listed below

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myid);
        Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"assets/fonts/Face Your  Fears.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(typeface,Typeface.BOLD);
    }
```

Comment: IS your font file having name as "Face Your  Fears.ttf" in assets/fonts folder?

Comment: Yes , Iv'e crossed  checked all that , but nothing changes , should i include anything else anywhere apart from this function

Comment: have you created `fonts` folder under `assets` or you have put the font file directly  to `assets` folder.

Answer (score 0):

`getAssets()` gives path for your assets folder,so no need to write `assets` again

in **"assets/fonts/Face Your  Fears.ttf"**
Try changing

```
Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"assets/fonts/Face Your  Fears.ttf");
```

to

```
Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Face Your  Fears.ttf");
```

The complete example for same ttf file implementation is here [Android Using External Fonts](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/)

Comment: @SainathS.R Clear you project Or remove existing app from device and try again.

Comment: Done , Its my3rd New Project

Comment: Is your .ttf file in assets/fonts folder.

Comment: I followed that method only Nothing changes

Comment: @SainathS.R what happened?Are you testing on emulator?